# Creating an calendar event using process builder

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, process-builder, configuration

I am trying to create a calendar event using Process Builder whenever a task is created.

I am passing the parameters as shown in the screenshot, but get an error like

> " FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Required fields are missing: [DurationInMinutes]"

Tried different combinations of start date time, end date time and duration but always get this error message. Any help to fix this issue is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `End Date Time` as `Now() + (60/24/60)` which is 60 minutes.

According to your post `Now()+1` is 1 day and not 1 hour.

Following process works for me

[image: Process]

Comment: Hi Santanu Thanks for your message. Tried changing End Date Time as you mentioned, but still get the same error. Also removed Duration and kept just the start date time and end date time. Tried keeping only the Start date time and Duration and removed the End date time. But always getting the same error.

Comment: updated my workable process with screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake. Had another Process builder trying to create an Event and that was causing the issue.
Deactivated the other Process Builder and its all good now.
Thanks!

Comment: you should close your question, and mark as answered. or delete it